# values are empty when saving html values of a form to database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form and I want to save a part of the form and some html to my database.

```
<div class="contract">

    <label for="Company_PostCode">Postcode</label>
    <input class="postcode valid" id="Company_PostCode" name="Company.PostCode" type="text" value="">

    <label for="Company_Address">Address</label>
    <input class="address valid" id="Company_Address" name="Company.Address" type="text" value="">

    // more form elements here

    <div class="text">
        some text here
    </div>
</div>
```

What I do is

```
$("#submit-button").on("click", function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".hidden-field").val($(".contract").html());

    if (/* some checks here */)
    {
        // blah blah
    }
    else
    {
        //submit form normally

        $("#form-register").submit();
    }
});
```

so I have a hidden field that I use to put the html that I want and post it to my controller.
The thing is that the values of my form are all empty..
$( ".contract" ).html() has all it's values empty.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your controller action please?

Comment: It's huge and I think it doesn't matter because from javascript console $( ".contract" ).html() shows empty input values.

Comment: Are you trying to save the whole html rather than the values in the `input` fields?

Comment: alert($(".contract" ).html());

Comment: yes, I want to save the whole contract div which is part of a form.

Comment: Can you not post the form normally and construct the html around the input values?

Comment: Construct the html with javascript? my input are like this: <input class="postcode valid" id="Company_PostCode" name="Company.PostCode" type="text" value=""> .. if I do a $("input#Company_PostCode").val( "something") it's not changing the html.

Comment: I meant for you to construct the html in the controller action not in the javascript. This would allow you to get the values and if you know the structure of the html you could add that in the controllers action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I found the answer...

$(".postcode").attr("value", $(".postcode").val() );
this must be done for each form element inside contract div. so the complete answer is...

```
$("#submit-button").on("click", function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.contract input').each(
            function(){
              $(this).attr( "value", $(this).val() );
            });
  $(".hidden-field").val($(".contract").html());

  if (/* some checks here */)
  {
      // blah blah
  }
  else
  {
      //submit form normally

    $("#form-register").submit();
  }
```

});

Answer (score 2):

I have tried your code in fiddle.it is working fine.I'm also getting the value from

```
 $( ".contract" ).html();
```

Also able to set this value to the hidden element.

Please Check this in fiddle
  http://jsfiddle.net/E6DCS/1/

Comment: @necronio still if u face pbm means let me know

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps I cannot express myself really well. If I type something at the input fields, these values are not appearing at the html that the alert box shows.

Comment: @necronio I understand what your problem is, the alert is 'seeing' the html as it was initially rendered and is not taking into account the value you have placed inside the input fields.

Comment: @necronio i think that is not possible

Comment: @necronio u can get the post code and address value but in that alert you cant expect that value..

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a hidden field. You could use a hidden div:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display: none;"></div>
```

and then set its html:

```
$( "#myDiv" ).val( $( ".contract" ).html() );
```

Also if you have more than one elements with `class="contract"` in your DOM you might consider using a stricter selector to pinpoint the actual element.

Comment: The hidden field is not my problem. The hidden field is used in order to post the result to my controller and this is working correctly. My problem is that the html itself has empty values. see: <input class="address valid" id="Company_Address" name="Company.Address" type="text" value="">

Comment: also, I have only one contract div.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#submit-button" ).on( "click", function( e )
{
   e.preventDefault();
     $('.address').attr('value',$('.address').val());
     $('.postcode').attr('value',$('.postcode').val());
     alert($( ".contract" ).html() );
     $( ".hidden-field" ).val( $( ".contract" ).html() );
     $( "#form-register" ).submit();
 });
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/E6DCS/2/